# React Native : StackNavigator Error : Invariant Violation : Element type is invalid

Tags: react-native

Getting this error (pictured below).  New to react-native and learning how to use the StackNavigator.  I believe it has something to due with export/imports but been stuck on this for a while.  Thank you.

index.js file

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNIntroduction', () => App);
```

App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'; 
import LoginScreen from './app/views/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './app/views/HomeScreen';

export default class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
    <Screens/>
   );
 }   
}

const Screens = StackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  HomeScreen : {screen: HomeScreen}
})
```

LoginScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-navigation';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View> 
            <Text> This is Login Screen </Text>
        </View>      
    );
 } 
}
```

My HomeScreen.js looks the same way as the LoginScreen.js.  I also included a pic the error itself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're importing React Native modules from `react-navigation` where there are none. Change to: `import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';`

Comment: @jkhedani  you sir are a gentlemen and a scholar.  Thank you so much for the quick response.  I was stuck on this for so long and overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change import statement `LoginScreen.js` to

```
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
```